# Create a global javascript event listener in ionic 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm a very beginner in ionic2/angular2 development.

I'd like to add a feature to display additional information / help in all my application.
This is usually done with tooltips or modal.

I've looked for tooltip in ionic2 but it seems it's not implemented yet, or doesn't work properly (works on mouseOver, but not on click event).
Or I didn't succeed to install it...

Concerning the modal, it seems there are not designed to display little help.

Concretly, I'd like to keep my DOM simple, something  like this :

```
Click <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Now you can see this text">here</span> to see the help.
```

So, I think I have to add a global listener in my application, because I would like to access it from every pages in my app.
In jQuery, it would be `$(document).on('click', '.tooltip', function(event) {...});`

How can I do that? And if I'm making a design mistake, please teach me the right way (but remember I'm noob :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: HostListener is what you need https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/listening_to_an_element_host.html

Comment: You could also do it like that: `<span (click)="showTooltip()">here</span>`

Comment: Did you look at the "Popover" from ionic? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/

Comment: @AndreasGassmann, the `<span (click)="showTooltip()">here</span>`  solution works well of course, but it involves to declare the showTooltip in each page right?
I'm going to look the other solutions. I had a look on Popover, but it seems it has the same cons as the Modal component.
I'm going to check more deeply. Thanks

Comment: I like the HostListener. Indeed, it seems to be the right solution for what I want to do